# HEROKU \AppData\Local\heroku\update.lock.readers.lock is locked

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, heroku-api

i try to login with command HEROKU LOGIN on windows but it gives error like this

```
autoupdate:: C:\Users\Lenovo PC\AppData\Local\heroku\update.lock.readers.lock is locked
 !    C:\Users\Lenovo PC\AppData\Local\heroku\update.lock.readers.lock is locked
```

what should i do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the update.lock.readers file in any editor and clear or delete the data or code inside the file, make it as a empty file. And run heroku again.